# RSS feed of hot questions during the week for specific tag

Tags: support, tags, feed, hot-questions

Hi guys,

I know you can get a RSS for specific tag. I also know you can get an RSS for hot questions during the week.

However, I can't figure out how to get RSS to both, e.g, RSS of this page:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/hot?filter=week

[EDIT]

Oops, I messed up, what I want is RSS of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week but filtered for a specific tag. Right now I can't even find the html version of that.

The original link I posted shows the hottest answers, not the questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of George and Yahoo Pipes I've created the feed that I wanted:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=fff97d235f6f7d14414873d14c887a37&_render=rss

Here is a link to the pipe:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=fff97d235f6f7d14414873d14c887a37

I am pretty sure it doesn't work exactly as I wanted but seems to be close enough.

**UPDATE**

I've improved the pipe to have arguments for StackExchange site, posts per week and tag:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=78ace2a2ae578e53b3f6d11c9acdd6c4

Comment: Looks pretty good to me!

Answer (score 2):

Will this do what you're looking for?

http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/questions?body=true&tagged=c%23&sort=votes

It's a custom feed generated by [stack2rss](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service), a small app I wrote.

Comment: Not quite... I was looking for something that will allow me to see the top voted questions in the last week... What is the API you're referring to in the link? Perhaps I could change it myself. Thanks!

Comment: @VitalyB: See [here](http://stackapps.com).

Comment: I guess I meant something like that: http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/questions?body=true&tagged=c%23&sort=votes&fromdate=1288639091 but the date has to be dynamic... I guess I could use Yahoo's Pipes for that, though not sure if it is worth the trouble.

Comment: Okie, I made the pipe. If it works, I will post it back here as a final answer. Thanks for the help! I'd upvote you, but I need 15 reputation to do so :|

Comment: @Vital: There. You have 15 rep. now :)

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted. And posted my feed as an answer.