# For a given set of tags top questions for week and month

Tags: support, tags

When you click on the image "MetaStackOverflow" or "StackOverflow", you will see Top Questions as shown in picture.

My favorite tags are for example Java and Algorithms, then is there any way I can find the top questions for a week and month from my chosen tags?

[image]

Comment: This should be a feature-request

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of... You could actually pull this [from the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?order=desc&sort=week&tagged=java&site=stackoverflow) and do something with it if you like (even [convert it to a feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62364/rss-feed-of-hot-questions-during-the-week-for-specific-tag)), but I can't find a way to expose it on the site.

You *can* get lists of hot *answers* for the [week](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/hot?filter=week) or [month](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/hot?filter=month) though.

Comment: doesnt look like the "from the api" link is working

Comment: Howso, @lordlupine?